# Are vector based generators the best way to create barcodes?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Is vector based generators the best way to generate barcodes? If yes, what are the namespaces that it will make use of? How is it used? Can anyone share some knowledge on this?

Comment: What? What barcodes are you talking about? Have you considered searching for a third-party library you can use?

Comment: @MarkByers Probably a regular barcode, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode.

Comment: I am talking about code39 or code 128 barcodes. Yes I have gone through many third party libraries and i don't want to use those libraries. I would like to render my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we are talking about [UPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code) like barcodes, vector based generation is not a must. It's the matter of representing some bits as vertical lines. So, you can easily do this using any graphic library or even using direct access to video buffer. You can represent a single bit with multiple pixels if you need a larger barcode. You don't need to use any interpolation I guess. But if you need a certain size (in pixels/centimeters etc.), vector based solution might be handful but still not a must.

C# source code example for generating scalable barcode graphics.

Steps:

1) Open a new C# Windows Forms sample project named `BarCode`.

2) Add a `PictureBox` and change `BackColor` to `White` and `Dock` to `Fill`.

3) Add `Load` and `Resize` events to `Form1`.

4) Copy & Paste the source code below over `Form1.cs` file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BarCode
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool[] barCodeBits;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int numberOfBits = 100;
            barCodeBits = new bool[numberOfBits];
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfBits; i++) {
                barCodeBits[i] = (r.Next(0, 2) == 1) ? true : false;
            }

            Form1_Resize(null, null);
        }

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int w = pictureBox1.Width;
            int h = pictureBox1.Height;

            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
            Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

            for(int pos = 0; pos < barCodeBits.Length; pos++) {
                if(barCodeBits[pos]) {
                    g.FillRectangle(b, ((float)pos / (float)barCodeBits.Length) * w, 0, (1.0f / (float)barCodeBits.Length) * w, h);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am talking about code39 or code 128 barcodes.I would like to render my own. I would be generating the barcode using C#. You mentioned direct access to video buffer how do we achieve that?

Comment: i was talking in general terms, not platform/language specific. using .NET, I'd recommend using GDI+. i guess you already know how to generate barcodes but you are searching for a way to render them as images, am i right? if so, i'll make an update to my question soon.

Comment: Yup tats rite.I have already working on how to draw each lines manually using bitmap?But finding it a bit difficult to drawing barcode lines.

Comment: The main question is how do i generate using vectors?

Comment: I've created a very basic example on how to create barcode like images which are scalable. There is no vectoral library behind, it's all GDI+ stuff. But you can always calculate your bar widths according to current width/height of the area. If you need a real vectoral output like SVG etc. this won't help. But if all you need is to see the image on the screen and/or print it out, that method will solve your problems. Of course this example only has random generated bars, nothing more. You need to create your own barcode generator engine. This is just a little sample.

Comment: Its really an awesome simple example.You are saying to encode the data i will have to create my own barcode generator.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to develop barcodes using vector based graphics. I fact have a look at [this link on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/BarcodeLibrary.aspx?fid=470627&fr=26#xx0xx) as most of the work is already done for you. This genrates a bitmap of the required barcode.

Comment: I have gone through many third party libraries and i don't want to use those libraries. I would like to render my own.

Comment: @Akshay -  The link is not to a third party library - it is to the full source to enable you to render your own!